# Contribute users can not delete Discussion items while they can delete Tracking items and Documents

Tags: 2013, permissions, administration, discussion-board, contribute

I have a Team site collection inside my sharepoint 2013. now inside the team site i have 3 lists, which share the same permissions:-

1. tracking list
2. Discussion list
3. docuemnt library

now users with Contribute Permission, are able to delete any tracking item AND any document. but when it comes to Discussions, users can only delete their own discussions . i try searching if there is any special option inside the Discussion list, and i found their is an item-level permission, but it is already set to allow users to create/edit all items:-

[image]

can anyone advice on this please ? how to allow contribute users to delete other discussions ?

Thanks

Comment: Under Advanced Settings there is an option to set permissions for Edit. Did you tried that?

Comment: @AmalHashim not sure i understand what are you referring to ?are you talking about the advance setting for the list?is so then the only option i got is the item-level permissions as shown in my question.. and it is not helpful for my case